# How do I minimize saved searches alert database cost?

Tags: database, database-design

I am working on a mobile application in which user stores  filtered products in a remote database table. Now I want to implement the alerts which user may achieve either by `FCM` or any `XMPP` mechanism. But my main concern is to reduce a cost of database operations as there may be thousand of users and their saved criteria and when ever some new product is added how it may map itself in particular criteria list. it seems to be much expansive.

Comment: Have you thought about "flipping" the logic. Store the criteria, and for each of them a lost of subscribed users. It'll be a bit more complex to implement the "save search" logic, but you'll save a lot by not having to potentially run the same query several times.

Comment: yup thats a bit of something I am worried about to handle things before theyget of of control